# Why reduce swappiness slowing down my notebook?

Tags: debian, kernel, swap

I don't want to know if I should have do this, but **why** this happens. The thing is: I have a notebook with 2GB of RAM and a minimal install of Debian 9 with XFCE. It boot with 120 MB of RAM (excluding the buff/cache). The use of RAM rarely exceeds 1500 MB when I am browsing on the web and doing my stuffs.

I have decide to change swappiness to "1" just to spare my SSD throught the /etc/sysctl.conf, and my two browsers (Firefox and Chromium) start to lagging a lot. Was nitid. They became paralyzed tortoises. Almost freezing.

Why this happens? I monitored the use of RAM and it never exceeded the 70% of capacity.

Comment: Reducing swappiness too much makes the RAM:swap ratio too unbalanced. Try a higher value, preferably over 10.

Comment: @Mioriin What value do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Anywhere between 40 and 70 should be fine. I just keep it at default since modern SSDs can handle several hundred terabytes of write cycles before degrading significantly, meaning that you'll probably have a new computer with a larger SSD long before the current SSD wears out from normal use. (source: https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead )

Comment: @Mioriin Thanks. I tried to change swappiness to 15 and the browser still lagging (to a lesser extent, but still). I will maintaining the default swappiness.